# Is there no simple way to read a local JSON or a TEXT file using plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, local

I have a local JSON file. I want to create an object of that file using JS.

I tried finding some solutions and they are simply too complicated

An answer suggests that "Being able to read a local file from your browser would be a major breach of security..." so does that mean that there is NO simple way to read a local file without using **FileReader** or **XMLHttpRequest** !?

I am very disappointed as I come from a Python background and there, you can simply use a one liner "open" function to read a file.

(PS: Please do not use any AJAX or jQuery in your answers/comments)

EDIT: Somewhat more detailed description.

I have 4 files in a folder. An HTML, a CSS, A JS and one JSON file. What I want is whenever, I try to load the HTML page in a browser, my JS creates a JSON object of my local JSON file which I can display in my HTML body.

Comment: What environment are you running your javascript in? In a browser, a `FileReader` is a very simple way to read a user-selected file in a webpage. In a node.js cli script, you definitely *can* simply open a file like in Python.

Comment: @Bergi its not a user selected file. I want my js code to read that file everytime I run the app.

Comment: Again, what app are you talking about? How do you "run" it? Please provide some context, so that we can suggest an appropriate solution.

Comment: @Bergi I just edited the question

Comment: Thanks. In that case, XHR (or the simpler `fetch` API) are your best solutions. You cannot access the local file system from within a browser as easily as a python program with full privileges could. A simple alternative would be to convert the JSON file to a JS file that defines a variable with the object, and load it as a script.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. I'll give XHR a try.